# Problems with computing a residue of a solution to an ODE

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, residue-calculus

I've been struggling with the following second order homogeneous ODE (equipped with an auxiliary parameter $t \in \Bbb{R}$)

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle A(z) {d^2 \over {dz^2}} F(z;t) \ + \
B(z) {d \over {dz}} F(z;t) \ + \
C(z) F(z;t) \ = \ 0 \\
\text{where} \\
\begin{array}{l}
A(z) \ = \ (1-t)z^3 + z^2 - z \\
B(z) \ = \ 5(1-t)z^2 + 3z - 1 \\
C(z) \ = \ (1-t)(4-t)z + (1-t)
\end{array}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

subject to the boundary conditions $F(z;1) = 1$ and
$F(z;0) = \big(1 - z -z^2 \big)^{-1}$. I've approached
this ODE using various methods (some of my attempts
are documented in this post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384700/young-fibonacci-version-of-nekrasov-okounkov). It occurred to me that one way to extract information about the solution would be to develop $F(z;t)$ as a
power series in $0<t<1$, namely

\begin{equation}
F(z:t) \ = \ g_0(z) \ + \ tg_1(z) \ + \ t^2g_2(z) \ + \ \cdots 
\end{equation}

where of course $g_0(z) = \big(1 - z -z^2 \big)^{-1}$
and then evaluate residues $\mathrm{Res}_p \big\{ g_n(z) \big\}$
for special values of $p \in \Bbb{C}$. If we take the $p$-residue
of both sides of the ODE (and integrate by parts) we obtain

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle 
\mathrm{Res}_p \Big\{ \big[ 6(1-t)z + 2 \big]F(z) \Big\}
\ - \ \mathrm{Res}_p \Big\{ \big[ 10(1-t)z + 3\big]F(z) \Big\} \\
\displaystyle
+ \ \mathrm{Res}_p \Big\{ \big[ (1-t)(4-t)z + (1-t)\big]F(z) \Big\} \\
= \\
\mathrm{Res}_p \Big\{ t \big[ (t-1)z - 1 \big]F(z) \Big\} \\
= \\
0 \end{array}
\end{equation}

In other words $\mathrm{Res}_p \big\{ F(z) \big\} =
(t-1) \, \mathrm{Res}_p \big\{ zF(z) \big\}$ or

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l} \displaystyle
\mathrm{Res}_p \big\{ g_0(z)  \big\} = - 
\mathrm{Res}_p \big\{ z g_0(z)  \big\} \ \ 
\text{and} \\
\displaystyle
\mathrm{Res}_p \big\{ g_k(z)  \big\} = 
\ \ \, \mathrm{Res}_p \big\{ z g_{k-1}(z) - zg_k(z)  \big\} 
\ \  \text{for $k \geq 1$}
\end{array} 
\end{equation}

This presents problems if, for example, we take $p = r_1$ to be a root of $1 - z - z^2 = -(z-r_1)(z-r_2)$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle
\ \mathrm{Res}_p \big\{ g_0(z)  \big\} \ = \ {1 \over {r_2 -r_1}} \\
\displaystyle \text{while} \\
\displaystyle
- \mathrm{Res}_p \big\{ zg_0(z)  \big\} \ = \ {r_1 \over {r_1 - r_2}}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Does this indicates that $p=r_1$ is a branch point
of the solution? Can someone help clear my confusion?

Many thanks, ines.